# Upload file with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, file-upload, selenium, attachment

Is it possible to upload file attachment with selenium in Python script?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18823139/6003362

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8665072/6003362

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If there is a form with file input on the page, I think it's straightforward to fill value in the input and submit the form with python api of selenium. You can find some sample code on the [document page](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#commands-and-operation)

Comment: Question is quite specific, while answer is pointing to hello world example for selenium in java. Down voting it.

Answer (score 9):

It can be done via:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("file")
element.send_keys("/home/pavel/Desktop/949IH3GNHAo.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to upload files is by using pyautogui. You can install pyautogui through pip

```
import pyautogui
... # set the webdriver etc.
...
...

self.driver.find_element_by_id("Open file selector").click()# This opens the windows file selector
pyautogui.write('C:/path_to_file') 
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpathToYourButton")
button.send_keys("fullPathToFile")
```

Now if you are in windows path to file uses backslash. To avoid issues **use double backslashes!** C:\ \Users\ ****\ \Desktop\ \1.jpg without spaces.

PS. I know its a from 4 years ago but I have been trying to figure this out for some time and someone might find this usefull...

Answer (score 0):

Python solution to upload a video to YouTube using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # Wait up to 5 sec before throwing an error if selenium cannot find the element (!important)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/upload")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
elem.send_keys("C:\\full\\path\to\\video.mp4"); # Window$
#elem.send_keys("/full/path/to/video.mp4"); # Linux
```

---

**Notes:**
1 - Be smart, go slowly but surely;
2 - YouTube max uploads per day is 50, but on the first day is 100;
3 - As of 2019, youtube api is limited to 5 video uploads (◔ _◔)

Answer (score 0):

give it a shot ytb_up based selenium.
inspired from bunch of auto upload youtube video library

https://github.com/wanghaisheng/ytb-up
features YOU MAY NEED

1. proxy support

auto detect whether need a proxy
2. cookie support

for those multiple channels under same google account
3. schedule time publish

you can explictly specify a date and time for each video or you can set publish policy and daily public count,for example,daily count is 4,you got 5 videos,then first 4 will be published 1 day after the upload date ,the other 1 will be 2 days after the upload date
4. fix google account verify

Answer (score -2):

it is quite simple, just record it using IDE. Upload command is working