# How to upload file ( picture ) with selenium, python

Tags: python, testing, file-upload, selenium, upload

How to upload a picture on a web application with the selenium testing tool? I am using python.

I tried many things, but nothing worked.

Comment: I posted an [answer here using python][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11872608/471376

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upload input control opens a native dialog (it is done by browser) so clicking on the control or browse button via Selenium will just pop the dialog and the test will hang.

The workaround is to set the value of the upload input via JavaScript (in Java it is done via JavascriptExecutor) and then submit the form.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300580/webdriver-file-upload) for sample in C#, I am sure there's also a way to call JavaScript in Python but I never used Selenium Python bindings

Comment: This is not a valid solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720794/jquery-select-input-file-and-also-set-it-to-another-input

Answer (score 197):

What I'm doing is this (make sure drv is an instance of webdriver):

```
drv.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

and then find your submit button and click it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what `os.getcwd()` does and where in your example `image.png` is located on your file system.

Comment: Sure! [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) returns the current working directory. `image.png` is located right next to the running script in the same directory.

Comment: This is the perfect way to do it. I should point out that the form needs to have an ID and it helps if the button does too!

Comment: What makes you say that Tobias K? What does not work?
All my Selenium experience has come from Linux environments.

Comment: So if I am actually looking at the spreadsheet, how can I upload the image / find the ID/Xpath

Comment: There is an upload button on the website where I want to upload my image.The upload buttons opens a dialog box for uploading image. But when I find the element(upload button) using class_name, I am not able to upload image using elem.send_keys('path/of/image'). What should I do?

Comment: Side-note: Multiple-file upload is also possible with send_keys - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955430/selenium-webdriver-upload-multiple-files

Comment: Is anyone aware of a solution like this that supports supplying multiple files at once?

Comment: If the web page does not have an input `type="file"` - this does not work. It doesn't treat the case for dropareas

Answer (score 32):

A very easy way to control components like windows file selector (or just your OS in general) is by using pyautogui. You can install pyautogui through pip

```
import pyautogui
... # set the webdriver etc.
...
...
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Open file selector']"))  # Example xpath

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(element_present).click() # This opens the windows file selector

pyautogui.write('C:/path_to_file') 
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was not given more votes. It is by far the most elegant and simple solution considering it is also cross platform. I was struggling for hours trying to find something that would work and was simple. I found had to make a couple of changes though because the `enter` option was not being recognized. `pyautogui.write(filepath, interval=0.25) 
        pyautogui.press('return')`

Comment: That helped a lot! Just make sure you use python selenium.

Comment: Does this work when using selenium in "headless" mode where there is no actual browser gui being created?

Comment: @alexpotato No that's true, but if the file selection window turns up I think this could work.

Comment: @eddyizm I'm doing exactly what you suggested, but pyautogui hits enter in my ipynb notebook instead of the window to confirm the file choice. Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: @R.Kulebyakin I'm not 100% sure about this but If you have multiple screens you can try to move the browser window to your main screen since pyautogui can only control your main screen.

Comment: @XRaycat thanks for your reply! I fixed the problem by running both .write and .press in one cell. But now the file is just not being attached for some reason. Having said that I see how the path is typed and then the "enter" button is clicked...

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` before `pyautogui.write('C:/path_to_file')` guarantees reliable result I guess

Answer (score 13):

I am using [fine-uploader](https://docs.fineuploader.com), running selenium tests with `pytest` and this worked for me:

```py
elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
elm.send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/tests/sample_files/Figure1.tif")
```

No form submission or Enter key is needed in my case.

Comment: If the web page does not have an input type="file" - this does not work. It doesn't treat the case for dropareas

Answer (score 10):

I added an answer for anyone looking to use deal with the annoying msofiledialogs. This is working off of saravanan's proposed solution, but more fleshed out for Python.

I had a similar problem with a script I'm working on for a company on the side. I'm attempting to upload documents for a company's clients, but due to the way their site worked, I could not utilize send_keys to directly send the path, so I had to rely on msofiledialog.

1. You only need to install AutoIt
   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3 or just "pip install -U pyautoit" through the cmd screen
2. type "import autoit" on your script page
3. Type the following before the file dialog pops up in your script:

   autoit.win_active("Open") 
   autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1",r"C:\Users\uu\Desktop\TestUpload.txt")
   autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1","{ENTER}")

It will look for the open file dialog window and fill it out and press enter.
"Open" is the title of my file dialog screen. Put the title of yours in place of "Open". There are more creative ways to utilize AutoIt's functions, but this is an easy, straightforward way for beginners.

Edit: DO NOT. DO NOT use control_send on most things if you can avoid it. It has a well-known issue of sending erroneous text. In my case, the colon in my file path was being turned into a semi colon. If you need to send input keys, it should be fine, however if you need to send text, use control_set_text. It has the same syntax.

```
autoit.control_set_text("Open","Edit1",r"C:\Users\uu\Desktop\TestUpload.txt")
```

Comment: Is this only for Windows?

Comment: @Noctsol Please help me.Iam also using autoit but it is uploading sometimes & sometimes not able to identify file dialogue box

Comment: I'm no longer doing this kind of thing, but if I had to guess. Are you triggering the file dialogue box on time? autoit should be reliable. Try adding a time.sleep(n) condition right before you call the auto.

Answer (score 7):

All these approach wont work with modern image uploaders in olx !!!
Alternative approach (only for windows )

```
1. Automation of windows can be done using Autoit 
2. Install Autoit and SciTe Script editor 
3. Autoit code :(imageupload.au3)

WinActivate("File Upload");  for chrome use "open" that is the name of the window that pops 
send("D:\images\image1.png");  path of the file
Send("{ENTER}")

4. compile it to get an .exe file(imageupload.exe)
5. Now from python call the .exe file like

import os
import os.system('C:\images\imageupload.exe') #path of the .exe file
```

Comment: can you give a clear example, do you import the exe and how do you call it exactly?

Comment: Nope! create a new autoit file with the three lines that I have given in my 3rd point. Refer this to convert it into .exe file https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/compiler.htm                                then you can call the exe file from python script using the two lines i have given in 5th point

Comment: Some ideas for linux?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code that i used:

```
Imagepath = "C:\User\Desktop\image.png"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/input').send_keys(Imagepath)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/button').click()
```

I accept the Answer by karloskar. Note It is not working for FireFox (59). And it is works with Chrome Driver only.

Comment: I guess WebDriverWait can be useful here

Answer (score 3):

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")   
shell.Sendkeys("C:\text.txt")  
shell.Sendkeys("~")
```

Will resolve the issue

Comment: Hi i need your help here, i am trying to upload image file and use this code but doesn't works for selecting file.its not fires enter event or tab keys. can you please help me?

Comment: Sendkeys support other key？

Answer (score 3):

Use PyAutoGui if sendkeys function is not working on buttons.

sample code:

```
import pyautogui
driver.find_element_by_xpath("Enter Xpath of File upload button").click()
time.sleep(4) #waiting for window popup to open
pyautogui.write(r"C:\Users\AmarKumar\FilesForUploading\image.jpg") #path of File
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily add this one line of code to solve the problem:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("your fullpath").send_keys("C://1.png(your file root")
```

But pay attention, sometimes maybe you put a wrong `xpath` in first field. follow below steps for reach to rightful `xpath`:

1. open the inspect and click exactly on the box which you want to
   upload the file.
2. right click on the `html` code and select `xpath` full address from copy
   sub menu.
3. paste the root in `xpath` field in the code.

[image]

Comment: A better formatting may be useful for the answer.

Comment: I did change a little for better looking.

Comment: Answer need to have code. (not screenshots)

Comment: screenshot is for getting the `xpath` full address which you can't reach with code.@Ratery

Comment: @MortezaOskuei Any time, welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

full code to achieve file upload using autoit tool.
u can just copy paste this and u can run, it will work since it is a acti-time demo.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os

def fileUploading():

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://demo.actitime.com/login.do");
    driver.find_element(By.ID,"username").send_keys("admin")
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "pwd").send_keys("manager")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[.='Login ']").click()
    wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='popup_menu_icon'])[3]")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='popup_menu_icon'])[3]").click()
    wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Contact actiTIME Support')]")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Contact actiTIME Support')]").click()
    wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='dz-default dz-message']")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='dz-default dz-message']").click()
    os.system("C:\\Users\\mallikar\\Desktop\\screenUpload.exe")
    time.sleep(2000)

fileUploading()
```

below is the content of autoit code:

```
WinWaitActive("File Upload")
Send("D:\SoftwareTestingMaterial\UploadFile.txt")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

download autoIt and autoIt SCITE editor tool.
once done install autoit and the open the scite editor and paste the above code and save it with .au3 extension and once saved, right click on the file and select complile script(x64), now .exe file is created.

now use the below code:

```
os.system("C:\\Users\\mallikar\\Desktop\\screenUpload.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.example.org")
    def upload_file():
        upload_file = driver.find_element_by_id("paste here id of file which 
        is 
        enter code here`shown in html code...")

       upload_file.send_keys("copy the path of file from your pc with name and 
       paste here...")
```

**if toast message is disappeared within seconds you can use Chropath extension in chrome to find its xpath**

> This is a pure python code.

Comment: Hi GHULAM NABI. Please consider adding more information because if the link becomes obsolete, this answer doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `control_send`, use `control_set_text` to resolve inconsistencies present in the string sent to the window. See this link for reference: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/85929-incorrect-string-being-sent-via-controlsend/

```
import autoit

autoit.win_wait_active("Open")
autoit.control_set_text("Open", "Edit1", imgPath)
autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: this is the best solution i see here. Only the last line might be weak if during execution some other window gets to foreground and autoit.send("{ENTER}") will be send to that windows. the work around is to use autoit.control_click("Open", "Button1") instead. worked perfect for me even when window is in background.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below script format to upload the images. This may help you.

```
   Imagepath=os.path.abspath('.\\folder1\\subfolder2\file1.jpg')
   driver.find_element_by_id("Id of the element").clear()            
   driver.find_element_by_id("Id of the element").send_keys(Imagepath)
```

if you do not have ID of the object ,then you can use xpath or css selector accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using splinter :

browser.attach_file('file_chooser_id',fully_qualified_file_path)

Comment: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'attach_file'

Answer (score 0):

## If you are using service you will get an exception

```py
service = Service('driver_path')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
choose_image = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'id')
choose_image.send_keys(os.getcwd()+'/image.jpg')
```

## Exception :

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: unknown command: session/$sessionId/se/file
```

## Working code (suggestion - use id of the element instead of other)

```py
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
choose_image=driver.find_element(By.ID, 'id')
choose_image.send_keys(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'image.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to upload multiple pictures, you can alter the [single image answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10472542/1256347) as follows:

```py
images = ["/path/to/image1.png", "/path/to/image2.png","/path/to/image3.png"]
drv.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys("\n".join(images))
```

Note that the input form should have the [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#multiple) attribute set to True.

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution that i consider best. it is a modification on solution by @sherlock (see my comment on that post)

```
import autoit
    
autoit.win_wait_active("Open")
autoit.control_set_text("Open", "Edit1", imgPath)
autoit.control_click("Open", "Button1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Install these three

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-tk python3-dev
pip install tk
pip install PyAutoGUI
```

use these two line of code.

```bash
pyautogui.write('/home/image.jpg')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pyautogui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import autoit
import subprocess

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.imagetotext.io/")
time.sleep(5)

element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Browse')]"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(element_present).click() # This opens the windows file selector

# Activate the file dialog box using AutoIt
autoit.win_activate("Open")

# Call the AutoIt script to handle the file upload dialog
# Path to the AutoIt compiled EXE file
autoit_exe_path = 'script.exe'

# Run the AutoIt script
subprocess.call(autoit_exe_path)

time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?