# How will you type a text into the input file element in Selenium 2 (Python driver)?

Tags: python, file, selenium

The common problem in Selenium is typing a text into the input element (`type="file"`). This action cannot be done using JavaScript due to security reasons.

Normally (with other input, or with a file input but using Selenium IDE) this would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("inputFileId").send_keys("/tmp/tmp.txt")
```

But this doesn't work at all.

Some solution I found are:

- Use *chrome environment type rather than *firefox or *iexplore.
- Set your `singed.applets.codebase_principal_support` to `true` in your Mozilla configuration.

None of them worked for me.

Is there any way to avoid this security restriction on Firefox in order to be able to run these tests?

Comment: Question has been asked a few times on SO, here's one that seems to have worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10472542/1257773

Comment: Thanks you your answer, but that does not work at all. The answer there is the one detailed above, which does not work. I couldn't find any solution for this. It is an actual restriction of JavaScript due to security reasons, therefore calling a JavaScript will not work neither.

Comment: I use the method you described to upload files with no problem whatsoever

Comment: Are you using python client and firefox? Can you share a piece of code please? It works using selenium iDE, but not running a test a python script, using selenium RC. Please confirm this. Thanks