# How to handle file upload windows in selenium webdriver + python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have come across solutions to handle file upload windows but unfortunately none of them talk about what APIs we have for python. Hence I thought to ask this question.

I have a web page with just a button named upload to open the file upload window. When I click on it, it opens the file upload window. I hope this is not a trivial question because I have not found good solutions over the internet which are specific to python.

Answer (score 0):

Just emulate click on "upload" button and supply path to your file with sendkeys.

[Answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665072/how-to-upload-file-picture-with-selenium-python)

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me so far... Is there a solution through javascript?