# Upload an image via ajax form with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, ajax, facebook, selenium

I'm trying to get familiar with selenium. I decided to try to work with `facebook`, and fulfill my profile with `selenium`. But they use too much `ajax`. It's not very complicated to fulfill my hometown and so on, but I don't really know how to upload an image. They have an `ajax` form to choose between upload and webcam photo. And then I need to handle somehow an upload dialog... any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665072/how-to-upload-file-picture-with-selenium-python ?

Comment: it's similar but not the same... there they just specify the path to the image and click Upload. You can go to facebook and look how they handle it. It is ajax form, then I get a dialog to choose a file...  But thanx, now I have a starting point :)

Comment: As I can see, there is a form `fbTimelineFileForm` in the page source. It is possible to submit it with javascript.

Comment: @alexvassel submitting... ok, `execute_script`. and what about choosing a file?

Comment: How about the solution from the link above (with specifying the path...)?

Comment: will try it right now

Answer (score 1):

So ok... it was much more easy than I thought. All I needed was to wait until ajax box with file input loaded and then just `send_keys` to it with image location.

```
        try:
            self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, u"sx_53a53c").click()
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, u"fbTimelineSelectorFileInput")))
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, u"pic")))
            self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, u"pic").send_keys("~/Downloads/z_ed6e1de4.jpg")
        except NoSuchElementException as nse:
            print 'Error. Element not found! '.format(nse.message)
        except:
            print "Something went wrong."
            import traceback
            type_, value_, trace_ = sys.exc_info()
            print traceback.format_tb(trace_)
```

Comment: Glad that my advice were helpful.