# jQuery, Select Input FILE and also set it to another INPUT

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The website has 2 input fields, I only select 1 field and the other one is invisible. Now I want to change the .val() of the invisible one to the .val() of the selected one, so both fields upload the same file. How does that work?

If I do this:

```
    $('#input_file').change(function() {
        var fileSelect = $(this).val();
        $('#hidden_input_file"]').val(fileSelect);
        console.log(fileSelect);
    });
```

I get this error: 
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your code is almost correct:

```
$('#hidden_input_file').val(fileSelect);
```

This will make jQuery change the value of an input. However, the *value* of `input type="file"` can never* be changed with JavaScript (nor Flash, nor any means programmatically). This is a security feature implemented in *all* end-user browsers to prevent websites from a trivial mischievery:

```
$('#hidden_input_file').on('blur', function (e) {
    $('#hidden_input_file').val('c:\passwords.txt'); // won't work
});
```

Enabling the programmatical change of a file URL that is to be uploaded from a user's computer would be a *monstrous* security issue.

**only applies to JavaScript on the web*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by waiting for the on change event of the original input

```
$("#Original").on("change", function (event) {
   let fileInputElement = document.getElementById('Picture');
   fileInputElement.files = event.target.files;
});
```