# "This operation is insecure" when using class properties as key

Tags: dictionary, angular, typescript

I have a custom `FileArgument` class that I'm using to store information about an uploaded file:

```
export class FileArgument {
  name: string;
  path: string;
  file: File;
}
```

My upload works fine and the server then returns the path where the file was uploaded. I then want to store this path in a dictionary using a previously set `fileArgument.name` as key. Below is a simplified overview of my component. `onSubmit()` is where the action is happening:

```
export class InputModuleComponent {
    private vsmodule: InputModule;
    private moduleArguments = {};
    private fileArgument: FileArgument = new FileArgument();

    @Input()
    module: InputModule;

    constructor(private inputModuleService: InputModuleService) {}

    onSubmit(): void {
        this.inputModuleService.postFile(this.fileArgument.file).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.moduleArguments[this.fileArgument.name] = response.filename;
                console.log(this.moduleArguments);
            },
            error => {}
        );
    }

    onFileChange(event): void {
        this.fileArgument.file = event.originalTarget.files[0];
        this.fileArgument.name = event.originalTarget.id;
    }
}
```

Line 14 above (`this.moduleArguments[this.fileArgument.name] = response.filename;`) causes the following error in Firefox:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

and in Chrome:

```
core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
```

If I replace that line with, for example:

```
this.moduleArguments['hello'] = response.filename;
```

I don't get any errors. The error clearly comes from using `fileArgument.name` as a dict key, but I have no idea why.

EDIT: The `postFile()` method from my service is below:

```
postFile (file: File): Observable<any> {
    console.log('input-module.service - postFile()');
    var url = this.uploadURL;

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        var formData: FormData = new FormData()
        var xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        formData.append("upload", file, file.name);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                    observer.complete();
                } else {
                observer.error(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

The component HTML:

```
<a (click)="modal.open()">
    {{vsmodule.displayName}}
</a>

<modal #modal>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <modal-header [show-close]="true">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Input Module - {{vsmodule.displayName}}</h4>
        </modal-header>

        <modal-body>
            <p>{{vsmodule.description}}</p>
            <hr>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let arg of vsmodule.args; let i = index">
                        <fieldset *ngIf="arg.type == 'file'">
                            <label>{{ arg.displayName }}</label>
                            <input 
                                name="{{arg.name}}" 
                                id="{{ arg.name }}"
                                type="file"

                                [(ngModel)]="moduleArguments[arg.name]"
                                (change)="onFileChange($event)" 
                            >
                            <p>{{ arg.description }}<p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </modal-body>

        <modal-footer>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Dismiss</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Run</button>
        </modal-footer>
    </form>
</modal>
```

Comment: Can you please share postFile method of InputModuleService?

Comment: @Sanket updated with the `postFile` method

Comment: Can you make a plunkr ? ;-)

Comment: Can you share the html of the view?

Comment: @ChrisSimon Updated with the component HTML

Comment: Edited my answer after reviewing the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `onChange`, `fileArgument.name` is set to the value of `event.originalTarget.id` - the id of an actual HTML element in the page

And chrome error is saying:

```
Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement'
```

Edit since you added the html - you have bound the 'moduleArguements' property to the file input element's ngmodel - as a result, changing that value will cause angular to try and modify the value property on the file input which is not permitted.

What is the purpose of updating that value? Is it just to feedback to the user?

If you remove the ngModel binding from the input element it should work - you are using the onFileChange event to capture the new filename anyway (although in the controller it is just onChange?)

Comment: That was exactly it. Obviously I'm still a noob. For the function name, I had changed it since I first wrote the post, my bad. On a side note, when we catch a `change` does that negate the `ngModel` binding?

Comment: Nope - catching a `change` will not interfere with the `ngModel` binding - they can and will both work independently.  In your case, there's no need for both, though as you're only using the `change` to get the value when the file is selected, you _could_ use the model binding instead, and use the bound variable as the input to the api request.  You just need to **not** use the same variable to record the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You cannot cannot actually change the value of the `this.moduleArguments[this.fileArgument.name]`as it would be a security issue.

Explaination: You would be changing the actual **value** of `this.fileArgument.name` to something else, which would allow other people with ill intent to do the same. Essentially, an attacker could change that name to redirect any attempts to use that file to another file. So, Java (or Flash, or any other programming language) could not **programmatically** change that due to security reasons.

With your work-around, you are not actually setting a `File` data member, therefore JS does not see this as a security hazard.

Remember, [almost] anything you can do involving website/server code (or code interacting with either), an attacker can do as well. That's why JS, in this case, blocks people from changing the content of this specific standard `File` object. Hope this helps!

Comment: (Deleted my previous comments) I appreciate the input but I believe there was a misunderstanding: `this.fileArgument.name` is just a string in my own class, it is **not** the `name` property of the `File` type. This answer is unfortunately incorrect. Just to re-iterate: my own `FileArgument`  class is **not** the same thing as the default `File`. If you take a look at the beginning of my question again, you'll note that there is a `File` object in my `FileArgument`, but I'm not modifying this object with user, or server, input.

Comment: Also, I'm not changing the value of `this.fileArgument.name`. I'm using `this.fileArgument.name` as a dictionary key.

Comment: My apologies. Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
var fileName = this.fileArgument.name;
this.moduleArguments[fileName] = response.filename;
```

and also if you are somewhere in JS changing the 'value' of your 

tag, you will get that error, please refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721020/2071008