# Angular2 Reactive forms - Set default value for form input field (input type=file)?

Tags: angular

i have to set default image path into formbuilder but given exception. i have also try with empty string and null.

```
 buildForm() {
        this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            location_id: this.formBuilder.control(null),
            image: this.formBuilder.control('assets/images-demo/avatars/user.png'),
        });
    }
```

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It is essential for browser security that the value cannot be set programmatically but only by a user action. Otherwise Javascript code would be able to retrieve files from the user's device. Exception: you can set it to the empty value, which is harmless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error says that it is not possible to set input programmatically for `type='file'`.

Only empty string is possible.

Many posts say that this is a security issue to change the input value for `file` type.

[jQuery, Select Input FILE and also set it to another INPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720794/jquery-select-input-file-and-also-set-it-to-another-input)