# How can I upload picture from system window using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried with this code. But can run it successfully. Can anyone help me for this ?

```
WinWaitActive("upload")
Send("E:\pic\newpic.jpg")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Have you had a look here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665072/how-to-upload-file-picture-with-selenium-python

Comment: Yes. I tried with all of this from above link. But it can't woork for me ?

Comment: Is there any other way to get the solution of my question ?