# How to add caption to image in Facebook using Selenium?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have been trying to get my head around selenium to upload image in Facebook. As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665072/how-to-upload-file-picture-with-selenium-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), I am able to do so using the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

But, how can I add the caption to the very image on facebook?

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use _Facebook API_ instead.

Comment: Oh, thank you. But, I am just trying to upload the image only. Does it also come under facebook scrapping? So, we aren't able to use selenium for facebook?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms, 3.2: _“You will not [...] access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission.”_