# How to upload an image with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to upload an image to a website using Selenium.

The HTML of the button which I have to click is in the image(Highlighted) below

[Upload Button Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gugsL.png)

The problem is when I click on that element a windows popup comes on the screen to select the image I want to upload, which I cannot control with Selenium.
[LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eDfh.png)

Please tell me How to Select the image from that popup and also tried the send_keys method but it was unsuccessful for me.

Comment: You have to use autoIt plugging to access the windows object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to install AutoIt "pip install -U pyautoit" through the cmd screen
2. type "import autoit" on your script page
3. Type the following before the file dialog pops up in your script:

   `autoit.win_active("Open") 
   autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1",r"Path with filename")
   autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1","{ENTER}")`

For you reference  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3

Please Note : Section 3 will be implemented after click on the button.
Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

From this [quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8733767/2558856), read:

> Upload input control opens a native dialog (it is done by browser) so
>   clicking on the control or browse button via Selenium will just pop
>   the dialog and the test will hang.

So, the solution from [here](http://www.seleniumstutorial.com/uploading-a-file-in-selenium-with-python/):

```
file_input = driver.find_element_by_id("uploadBtn")
file_input.send_keys("/absolute/path/to/file")
```