# Image upload with Slenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How can I upload the image in this line of code.

Detail, I need to click on the field where I'm going to upload the file, I can't use the command SEND_KEYS(file path)

Here's the code I'm using.

An alternative I found was pyautogui, but I didn't like it, because it uses the keyboard to execute the command.

```
    foto = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/i[1]").click()
    sleep(5)
    pyautogui.write(r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Facebook\Imagens\nome3.png")
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

screen that opens to upload the file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuSJp.png)

Comment: what does not work? How do you know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload file ( picture ) with selenium, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665072/how-to-upload-file-picture-with-selenium-python)

Comment: I want to upload the image using the command
sendkeys(image path, Keys.ENTER)

Comment: selenium can't control window with files - you should rather find `<input type="file">` and send text directly to this item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading file with Selenium is normally done with the following code:

```py
uploading_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
uploading_element.send_keys(path_to_the_file_to_be_uploaded)
```

In you case this should work:

```py
uploading_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
uploading_element.send_keys("C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Facebook\Imagens\nome3.png")
```

No need to send `Keys.ENTER`, no need to use `r` with path.
Make sure the page is properly loaded when you perform this action.
Possibly you will need to add  a wait, so your code can be as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys("C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Facebook\Imagens\nome3.png")
```