# How to enter file path?

Tags: python, selenium

How can I do to type something in the field of the image below?

I've tried without success:

```
from threading import local
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

`wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='file']"))send_keys("C:/Users/my_user/Downloads/doch.jpeg")`

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    actions.send_keys((row["message"]))
    actions.perform()
```

The only palliative solution was:

```
pyautogui.write((row["photo"]))
pyautogui.press("enter")
```

I don't want to use pyautogui as it uses the keyboard command and I can't do anything on the computer while the code is running.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows path you need double backslashes. Try this:

```py
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='file']"))send_keys("C:\\Users\\my_user\\Downloads\\doch.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can't upload files using the Windows select file option, so you'll have to do something else - you might be able to use the `send_keys` function, i.e.:

```py
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
elem.send_keys('C:\\Path\\To\\File')
```

Note that this may not work, depending on the type of input, and you may be able to instead simulate a drag-and-drop operation if the website supports this.

See [How to upload file ( picture ) with selenium, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665072/how-to-upload-file-picture-with-selenium-python) for more info

Comment: //input[@type='file']

does not exist on the page

Comment: I assumed it did because you had it in your question. Replace that with the xpath of the input.