# Upload file with Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I have tried the method from this page:
[Upload file with Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428102/upload-file-with-selenium-in-python)

Code:

```
file_button = browser.find_element_by_id('fileUploadProxy')
file_button.send_keys('/Users/home/Downloads/1-Students-and-Parent-Email.csv')
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 110, in <module>
    upload_students_results('Surname, Name')
  File "test.py", line 91, in upload_students_results
    file_button.send_keys('/Users/home/Downloads/1-Students-and-Parent-Email.csv')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 349, in send_keys
'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.96)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.4 x86_64)
```

Comment: Please show how the element with `id="fileUploadProxy"` is represented in HTML.

Comment: @alecxe <div id="fileUploadProxy" class="fileUploadProxy buttonWidget allButtons fileUploadButton">Choose File</div>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is - you are sending keys to the `div` element which is not "interactable", does not accept the keys - hence the "cannot focus element" error.

The idea behind the solution you've linked is to **send keys to the `input` element with `type="file"` that is responsible for the file upload**. Find this element in your HTML and send keys to it.

Note that this element could be invisible. In this case, you should first [make it visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25725701/771848) for the `send_keys()` to work.

---

**Update:**

Okay, now we at least know which element is our desired one:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload2" class="fileToUpload">
```

Since you have troubles locating this element, either try [waiting for it](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


file_upload = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fileToUpload2"))
)
file_upload.send_keys('/Users/home/Downloads/1-Students-and-Parent-Email.csv')
```

Or/and, check if this element is inside an `iframe` - if it is, you would need to switch into the context of the `iframe` and only then perform the element search.

Comment: I think I found it  `<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload2" class="fileToUpload">` so I changed the code to > `file_button = browser.find_element_by_id('fileToUpload2')` but it is still throwing an error? Also tried adding .click() too.

Comment: @Phil which error is thrown now? Is the element visible/editable?

Comment: Current error Part A > `File "test.py", line 88, in upload_students_results
    file_button = browser.find_element_by_id('fileToUpload2')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 282, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 784, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  `

Comment: Part B `File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"fileToUpload2"}`

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. and it also was in iframe. So I switch to by `driver.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_name('frame_element'))`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I inserted the file path as a string. This is functional:`file_input.send_keys(os.path.abspath("path/to/the/file.xyz"))`