# Upload file to Twitter with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, bots

I am trying to make a twitter bot and I am using Seleniumwith Python.

I have tried the method from this page: [Upload file with Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775752/upload-file-with-selenium-webdriver-python)

HTML:

```
<input accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/webp,image/gif,video/mp4,video/quicktime,video/webm" multiple="" tabindex="-1" type="file" data-focusable="true" class="r-8akbif r-orgf3d r-1udh08x r-u8s1d r-xjis5s r-1wyyakw" data-testid="fileInput">
```

Code:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id='react-root']/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input')
button.click()
button.send_keys('C://Users/Yagmur/Desktop/TwitterBot/2020-09-21data.png')
```

I can't upload pictures this code is not working[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3yNb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Selenium only works with web page. You could try with requests but it's very difficult to scrape/work with Twitter without Twitter API..