# How do I automate the process of uploading a file on selenium python to this pop-up window?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[This is the picture of the pop-up window that pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqoaV.png)

I can't find the proper web elements to automate the process of uploading a CSV file to this window.[Web-element page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77DyJ.png)

Comment: You can use `send_keys` with the path to the file as the parameter. However, the image shows an element that is a `div` which you can't send keys to. You will have to find the `input` tag corresponding to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43775885/3730626

Comment: That's what I attempted but there is no file element at all. I think it just some Java script given by the ::After if you look closely. In this case do you think there is anything I can do?